# Find latest date of document based on 2 separate fields: month and year

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

I have documents in mongoDB that look like this:

```
{username:String, paymentYear:Int, paymentMonth:Int}
```

I would like to find the latest document of a username, that means, the closest date to our Date.now(). What is the best way of accomplishing it? Is there any query of mongo I can use or should I write my own code?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/) aggregation date operator to build a `date` field (year, month, day=1, etc.) and then use it compare with `Date.now()`. You need to use the `$expr` operator to use the `$dateFromParts` operator for matching in the `find` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable using MongoDB's `$dateFromParts` stage Aggregation pipeline.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "tempDate": {
                "$dateFromParts": {
                  year : '$paymentYear', 
                  month : '$paymentMonth',
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {"tempDate": -1}  // Change from `-1` to `1` For Ascending Order
    },
    {
        "$limit": 1 // Number of documents to be returned based on the sort order
    },
])
```

Use can implement this in `$project` stage instead of `$addFields` stage based on your needs for better optimization.

> Note: This will work only for MongoDB version 3.6 and above.

Comment: I think you're missing the match stage before sort in order to define the highest date to search for. Else just getting the latest document  (sort by `_id`) for a given user would be enough, provided that `_id` generation is left to the database.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I forgot to add `$match` stage before `$sort` pipeline